# GParted cleared/unformatted partition vs Disk Utility's free space

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, disk-space

I just read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/706624/cleared-vs-unformatted-partition-in-gparted) Q&A, and I think I understand the point being made.

My reputation won't allow me to comment, but I would like to ask: is either *cleared* or *unformatted* an equivalent to what Mac's Disk Utility refers to as *free* space?

Answer (score 0):

- *Unformatted* means no well-known filesystem (i.e. NTFS, ext4, FAT...) is found on the partition. There *may be* one, but the computer did not find it or doesn't recognize it (i.e. ext4 disks seen as RAW in Windows...). However, the *unformatted* space still belongs to a disk partition.
- *Cleared* means that GParted will erase every marks of the well-known filesystem, effectively making the partition unformatted.
- *Free space* is any disk space that is **out** of a disk partition. Free space isn't and can't be formatted, or unformatted, because formats and filesystems belong to disk paritions, and free space is **not** a partiton.

If you have a partition seen as *unformatted* in GParted that is seen as *free space* in Mac Disk Utility, I really suggest you remove and burn the latter to ashes.

By the way, you should edit your question because readers shouldn't need to follow the link to the other Q&A you provided. Tell them what you see in your softwares and what information you would like to get. You might recieve downvotes if you don't.